# livecode and mergExt mergDropboxCreateFolder

Tags: livecode

i have done the link with my app in dropbox,my question how we use the  mergDropboxCreateFolder pPath to create a folder? the faq have no example or something to start from there :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're following the example stack, you simply utilise the stored path to the Dropbox folder that you're linked to (called sPath in that case) and use:

```
mergDropboxCreateFolder(sPath & "/" & "myFolderName")
```

This will create the folder in your local Dropbox folder and it will then be synchronised with your online Dropbox.